# Running WatiN Tests in TFS Build

Tags: watin, tfs2010

I have created a suite of WatiN tests and added them into Source Control. My team are new to using TFS and I am looking at how I can get the tests to run as part of a TFS Build that will build all the projects concerned, run our suite of Unit Tests and ran the Automated UI Tests created using WatiN.

At the moment, everything detailed previously gets done when the build is ran apart from the Automated UI Tests.

When editing the Build Definition, in the process section I set the Automated Tests to run matching **\test.dll using setting from [where the WatiN tests are stored in Source Control]. However, the tests have not being run.

Have been looking around for information on the best way to set them up and finding it hard to find what I am doing wrong.

If anyone can pass on any advice on what I am missing to get these tests running as part of the build would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you clarify: How do you normally invoke your Watin tests? And which TFS project are they in?

Answer (score 1):

The selected tests in

> matching **\test.dll using setting from [where the WatiN tests are
>   stored in Source Control]

are going to be executed with MSTest, which is not compatible with watin.

You can try to change the build template TFS uses to call your watin runtime instead of MSTest, but you'll have to create code

Answer (score 1):

No, you do not have to write code.
All you need to do is run your TFS in interactive mode, not in service mode because services are not allowed to open windows but watin doesn't work without a window.
You'll find the settings on tab build configuration.